# chinese grammar, 做饺子 or 做饭饺子?

Tags: grammar

做饺子 and 做饭饺子, second is said grammatically incorrect, by a Chinese person : is that right ? what is the problem with 做饭饺子

wenlin says : 做饭[-飯] zuòfàn* {E} v.o. prepare a meal | Nǐ huì zuòfàn ma? 你会做饭吗? Can you cook ?

Comment: `做` -> verb, `饭` -> noun, `饺子` -> noun. `做饭` -> verb-noun construction, correct. `做饺子` -> verb-noun construction, correct. `做饭饺子` -> verb-noun-noun ? Wrong.

Comment: 做饭  is a 离合词（separable verb）cf.＂现代汉语离合词用法词典＂：做饭：把米、面等粮食做熟，也泛指炊事活动。  **［离］**  （１）＂做＂后带助词＂着＂、＂了＂、＂过＂、＂的＂等：妈妈正做着饭呢，一会儿能吃了。／我为孩子们做了一辈子饭。／孩子们从不做过饭。／你什么时候做的饭？（２）＂做＂后带补语：我做好饭才去上班。（３）＂饭＂提到＂做＂前：把饭做好她就上班去了。（４）重叠＂做＂我退休后在家做做饭，洗洗衣服、挺清闲的。（５）＂饭＂前带定语：今天做什么饭？  **［合］**  （１）合任主语：做饭我能胜任。（２）合任谓语：她正在做饭。（３）合任宾语：你应该学学做饭。（４）合任定语：做饭的时间还没到呢，你着什么急？（４）合带状语：我每天都要做饭。  **［误］**  我老是做饭不好。  **［正］**  我老是做不好饭。

Comment: 做饭饺子 - means make dumplings filled (only) with rice....doesn't sound good

Comment: It might seem that there are verbs of type verb+object which can be followed by another object, e.g. 打印：打印一个文档，打印报告，打印出图像，could users provide more examples of such verbs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character "饭" itself in the word "做饭" has a literal meaning as "meal". So if you say "做饭饺子", the whole meaning of the sentence would become "prepare 'meal dumplings'", it contains a strange phrase "meal dumplings" (饭饺子) which is not in the regular Chinese vocabulary.

In this sense, "饭" is just a generic character referred to any kind of meal, if you mean to refer to a specific type of food, you should just replace "饭" with that food such as "饺子".

Comment: ok, i understand ! it looks like when we say in french : "monter là-haut" or " descendre en-bas" we call that a " pléonasme ", a pleonasm !

Answer (score 1):

Mandarin is not difficult. However, usage are varied depends on regional custom.

Although rice is Chinese main staple, it can't growth in Northern region. And Beijing mandarin love to use the word "做" as noun for actions, or preparation. 
Thus 做饭 become synonym of cooking in Beijing mandarin.

In Southern China, where the rice is growth, a straight forward verb is used : 
煮饭. So in Guangdong region, when people say 煮饭, it means cooking, not about cooking rice, but prepare the meals. And southerner love to use explicit meaning, thus, wrapping dumpling "包饺子" .

Answer (score -1):

it's just 做饺子 (the 饭 is redundant)

做饺子or 包饺子